# How to get rid of "chaning" rows above headers (lenght changes everytime but headers and data are always the same)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, header

I have the following csv file: 
[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbn7N.png)

there are about 6-8 rows at the top of the file, I know how to make a new dataframe in Pandas, and filter the data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('payments.csv')
df = df[df["type"] == "Order"]
print df.groupby('sku').size()
df = df[df["marketplace"] == "amazon.com"]
print df.groupby('sku').size()
df = df[df["promotional rebates"] > ((df["product sales"] + df["shipping credits"])*-.25)]
print df.groupby('sku').size()
df.to_csv("out.csv")
```

My issue is with the Headers. I need to
1. look for the row that has date/time & another field. 
That way I do not have to change my code if the file keeps changing the row count before the headers.
2. make a new DF excluding those rows. 
What is the best approach, to make sure the code does not break to changes as long as the header row exist and has a few Fields matching. Open for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

considering a CSV file like this:

```
random line content 
another random line 
yet another one
datetime, settelment id, type
dd, dd, dd
```

You can use the following to compute the header's line number:

```
#load the first 20 rows of the csv file as a one column dataframe
#to look for the header 
df = pd.read_csv("csv_file.csv", sep="|", header=None, nrows=20)
# use a regular expression to look check which column has the header 
# the following will generate a array of booleans 
# with True if the row contains the regex "datetime.+settelment id.+type"  
indices = df.iloc[:,0].str.contains("datetime.+settelment id.+type")
# get the row index of the header 
header_index = df[indices].index.values[0]
```

and read the csv file starting from the header's index:

```
# to read the csv file, use the following:
df = pd.read_csv("csv_file.csv", skiprows=header_index+1)
```

### Reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd 
from StringIO import StringIO 


st = """ 
random line content 
another random line 
yet another one
datetime, settelment id, type
dd, dd, dd
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(st), sep="|", header=None, nrows=20)
indices = df.iloc[:,0].str.contains("datetime.+settelment id.+type")
header_index = df[indices].index.values[0] 

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(st), skiprows=header_index+1)

print(df)

print("columns")
print(df.columns)
print("shape")
print(df.shape)
```

Output:

```
  datetime  settelment id  type
0       dd             dd    dd
columns
Index([u'datetime', u' settelment id', u' type'], dtype='object')
shape
(1, 3)
```